# Conditional Probability: Exponential and Multinomial

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, hierarchical-bayesian

### Problem

There are 10 different drinks, labelled as $d_1,\cdots,d_{10}$, a runner can take during a marathon, each time he stops he takes (randomly) one drink, before running again. The distance (or elapsed time $\Delta t$) he can cover before stopping for another drink depends on the type of drink he took previously. What is the probability that on his next stop he would go for drink $d_i$ given that he ran for $\Delta t$?

### Solution

Let $X$ be the r.v. for the run time event in terms of $\Delta t$, and let $Y$ be the r.v. for the type of drink, such that $x\in X$ and $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Further, let $\mathbf{y}=[y_1,\cdots,y_n]^{\text{T}}$, so that $\mathbf{y}\in Y$ and $y_i\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$. That is, $y_i$ is the number of occurrence of the type of drink he took for the entire race. Then, the probability that he would go for drink $d_2$ can be specified as $\mathbf{y}=[0,100,\cdots,0]^{\text{T}}$, i.e. all other index to zero except the second index which corresponds to $d_2$=100, assuming there are 100 independent trials. We can solve this using conditional probability as follows:
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(Y =\mathbf{y}|X = x)&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y = \mathbf{y},X = x)}{\displaystyle\int_{\forall \mathbf{y}\in Y}\mathbb{P}(Y = \mathbf{y},X = x)\operatorname{d}\mathbf{y}}\\
    &=\frac{f_{Y,X}(\mathbf{y}, x)}{\displaystyle\int_{\forall \mathbf{y}\in Y}f_{Y,X}(\mathbf{y}, x)\operatorname{d}\mathbf{y}}\\
    &=\frac{f(x|\mathbf{y})f(\mathbf{y})}{\displaystyle\int_{\forall \mathbf{y}\in Y}f(\mathbf{y}, x)\operatorname{d}\mathbf{y}}.
\end{align*}
$f(\mathbf{y})$ is the prior distribution which can be assumed as multinomial distribution, and $f(x|\mathbf{y})$ is the likelihood function which in this case is an exponential distribution.

The prior distribution as mentioned above is a multinomial distribution given below:
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{P}(Y=\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})=f_Y(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol{\theta})=\begin{cases}
    \displaystyle\frac{n!}{y_1!\cdots y_n!}\theta_1^{y_1}\cdots\theta_k^{y_n},&\;\text{when }\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = m\\[0.3cm]
    0,&\;\text{elsewhere}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
$m$ is the total number of independent trials.

The likelihood function is a hierarchical model given by:
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(X=x|Y=\mathbf{y},\Lambda=\lambda)&=\mathbb{P}(X=x|Y=\mathbf{y},\Lambda=\lambda)\mathbb{P}(\Lambda=\lambda|Y=\mathbf{y})\\
    &=f_{X|Y,\Lambda}(x|\mathbf{y},\lambda)f_{\Lambda|Y}(\lambda|\mathbf{y})\\
    &=f(x|\mathbf{y},\lambda)f(\lambda|\mathbf{y})
\end{align*}
Since $X\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$, then $f(x|\mathbf{y},\lambda)f(\lambda|\mathbf{y})=f(x|\lambda)f(\lambda|\mathbf{y})$. Further,
\begin{align*}
    f(x|\lambda) &= \lambda e^{-\lambda x},\\
    f(\lambda|\mathbf{y};\beta,\alpha) &= \displaystyle\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\lambda^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta\lambda}.
\end{align*}

### Question

How do I incorporate the effect of $\mathbf{y}$ in the likelihood function? As seen from above the likelihood is $f(x|\mathbf{y})$, but that end up with:
\begin{align*}
    x|\lambda &\sim Exp(\lambda)\\
    \lambda|\mathbf{y},\beta,\alpha &\sim Gamma(\beta,\alpha)
\end{align*}
$\mathbf{y}$ is not incorporated in the Gamma model. Is the above attempt correct?